# Shipping calculator not returning correct results

Tags: c

The assignment is to write a shipping calculator using the following information.

Packages above 50 pounds will not be shipped. You need to write a program in C that calculates the shipping charge.

The shipping rates are based on per 500 miles shipped.  They are not pro-rated, i.e., 600 miles is the same rate as 900 miles or 1000 miles.

Here are the shipping charges -

Package Weight                                                                                Rate per 500 miles shipped

```
Less than or equal to 10 pounds                                                      $3.00
More than 10 pounds but less than or equal to 50 pounds            $5.00
```

If the shipping distance is more than 1000 miles, there is an additional charge of $10 per package shipped.

I originally started writing the program using double but wanted to used a trick I had seen on here to always force the program to round up for the shipping charges by adding 499 to distance then dividing by 500.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int Shipping, packageWeight, packageDistance, packagePrice;


printf("Enter the weight of the package: \n");
scanf("%d", &packageWeight);
printf("The weight you have entered is %.2d\n", packageWeight);



if (packageWeight <= 10 )
    Shipping = 3.00;

if (packageWeight <= 50 && packageWeight > 10 )
    Shipping = 5.00;

if (packageWeight > 50.0) {
puts("Sorry, we only ship packages of 50 pounds or less.");
return 0;
}

printf("How far are you sending the package? \n");
scanf("%d", &packageDistance);
printf("The distance you entered is %.2d\n", packageDistance);



if (packageDistance <= 1000){
    packagePrice = (packageDistance + 499 / 500) * Shipping;
    printf("The shipping charge is %.2d \n", packagePrice);
    system("pause");
    }


if (packageDistance > 1000) {
    packagePrice = (packageDistance + 499 / 500) * Shipping + 10.00;
    printf("The shipping charge is %.2d \n", packagePrice);
    system("PAUSE");
}

}
```

With a weight of 10 and distance of 501 the output should be a shipping charge of 6 but was 1503
Based on a a weight of 20 and a distance of 1001 the program should output a shipping charge of 25 but was 5000

Comment: `499 / 500` is 0 (integer division).  Try re-working the calculation.

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I've run in to another problem. when I input a weight of 1.5 for the package I end up with a ridiculous output. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: "How would I go about fixing that? " is too vague.  Post your code, inputs  used, output seen, output expected.  Tip: check the return values from `scanf()`.

Comment: Note: when you input a weight of 1.5pounds and are reading the input via `%d`, the value read will be 1,  Then when trying to read the distance to ship, the call to `scanf()` will fail.  Suggest reading the weight with `%f` into a `float` variable.   Note: `scanf()` returns the number of successful `input format specifier conversions` (or EOF)  Any value returned other than the number of `format specifiers` indicates an error occurred

Answer (score 2):

You have mess with integers / doubles, output, expressions, etc.

Let me show you why you get 1503:

```
if (packageDistance <= 1000){
    packagePrice = (packageDistance + 499 / 500) * Shipping;
    printf("The shipping charge is %.2d \n", packagePrice);
    system("pause");
}
```

Your packageDistance is 501 then if statement is true and you get inside.

Then you setup package price. First you get packageDistance which is 501. Then you add it with 499/500 which is 0 since 499 < 500 and you attempt to get integer part of division (as per C/C++ standard). The sum of 501 and 0 is 501.

Now, you multiply it with Shipping. The value you set is 3.0, but smart C convert it to integer 3. 501 * 3 is 1503 and you get the result.

Finally, you try to sent output as %.2d. This is nonsense and I am surprised C shows something at all, but I believe it just see d and ignores .2

This is what you have to do:

1. Understand your business logic (you do)
2. Be careful with integers and floating point numbers, read C documentation or send questions here if you do not understand something.
3. Make sure you use brackets when needed: a + b / c is not the same as (a + b) / c
4. Make sure you do not use integer division if you mean to use "regular" division.
5. Make sure you use %d for integers and %.2f for floating point numbers when appropriate.

Comment: Note: `"%.2d"` is well defined by the C library.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am not even going to argue, C compiler does more strange things, but I do not understand what it is and why 1503 was output if .2 has some meaning...

Comment: "An optional precision that gives the **minimum number of digits** to appear for the d, i,
o, u, x, and X conversions"

Comment: hm... I usually use %02d for that, but it make sense, so 1503 is the right answer with legal code

Comment: `"%02d"` is a minimum _width_, not _digits_.  Makes a difference with sign and prefixes.  OP could have used `"%d"` here.  IAC, the format is ancillary to the main issue.  UV.